# set local ad distro group -ReportToOriginatorEnabled $true

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to set all the local AD Distros to have the attribute of -ReportToOriginatorEnabled $true

set-adgroup says it doesn't recognize the attribute and
set-Set-DistributionGroup prompts me for my user credentials to connect to office 365 (we have a hybrid sync setup)

**how would I set the local groups attribute?**

```
    $groups= get-adgroup -Properties name,mail -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=company,DC=local";

    foreach($group in $groups)
    {
        if($group.mail ){
            Write-Host $group.mail    
            Set-DistributionGroup $group.mail -ReportToOriginatorEnabled $true -whatif
            Set-adgroup $group.mail -ReportToOriginatorEnabled $true -whatif
        }   
    }
```

Comment: if you have a hybrid setup, why don't you just set this in office 365 (exchange online)? Not everything is set in the local AD in a hybrid setup.

Comment: my understanding is that local settings will take precedence over the cloud version. I do have some cloud only distros and the  Set-DistributionGroup works on for that

Comment: Can you not just run `Set-ADGroup $group -Replace @{reportToOriginator="TRUE"}`?

Comment: I’ll give it a try